# Overwrite Bootstrap's property

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using "img-responsive" bootstrap class, but I would like to remove one of its properties.

My html code:

```
<a id="removeBSproperties">
    <img height="250" width="270" class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="test.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Bootstrap sets the img height: auto. I want to remove it.

I tried using:

```
#removeBSproperties img{
    height: none;
}
```

It doesn't work. I'm new using CSS. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: we don't have `height: none;` in CSS! it must be `height: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you don't set the image height via HTML, but set it with CSS, like so:

```
#removeBSproperties img{
    height: 250px !important;
}
```

If you wanted to get rid of the `height` property in CSS, you can set it to `height:initial`, `height:inherit`, `height:auto` or `height:100%`, depending on what you are trying to achieve. More info on CSS `height` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using "img-responsive" bootstrap class, but I would like to remove one of its properties.

You can avoid setting  the image height with `HTML`.  Set it with `CSS` and you can remove the height property in `CSS`, you can set it to

`height: initial`
`height: inherit`
`height: auto`

Hope this will answer your question.